# A problem about the tranform from converge in distribution to converge in probability

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution

Recently, I found some parts in the proof that I can't identify why. Please help me to explain the following:

Suppose $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X_n}-\mu)$ converge in distribution to $N(0,\sigma$). Then, the textbook directly derive $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X_n}-\mu)^2$ converge in probability to zero.

My idea is to construct a Chebyshev inequality to prove this. But I can't identify the form.

Sorry for my writing but the main wish is to help for some hints or explanations on how to prove this. Thanks for any advice or help!!!

Comment: You can use the Markov inequality for nonnegative random variables $Y_n$ and for all $\epsilon>0$: $$P[Y_n\geq \epsilon] \leq \frac{E[Y_n]}{\epsilon}$$ for $Y_n=\sqrt{n}(\overline{X}_n-\mu)^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $Y_n \to Y$ in distribution then $f(Y_n) \to f(Y) $ in distribution for any continuous function $f$. Taking $f(x)=x^{2}$ it follows that $n(\bar{X_n}-\mu)^{2}$ converges in distribution. Now use the fact that if $Y_n$ converges in distribution  then $\frac 1 {\sqrt n} Y_n \to 0$ in distribution and convergence to $0$ in distribution  implies convergence in probability to $0$.

Hint for an alternative proof. $P(\sqrt{n}(\bar{X_n}-\mu)\leq x) \to \Phi(x)$ **uniformly**. Now you can write $P(\sqrt{n}(\bar{X_n}-\mu)^{2}>\epsilon)=P(\sqrt n|(\bar{X_n}-\mu)|>\sqrt {\epsilon} n ^{1/4})$ and note that $1-\Phi (\sqrt {\epsilon} n ^{1/4}) \to 0$.

Comment: @GongYu There was  a typo at the end. I wrote $\Phi$ for $1-\Phi$.

Comment: Thanks for your alternative proof. Really good hints for me to understand. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @GongYu If you are satisfied with the answer you can consider voting/approving. Otherwise, the question will remain in the unanswered question list.